# How to prove the equation $\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{\textbf{r}(\theta)}{|\textbf{r}(\theta)|^2}=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\textbf{r}(\theta)$ be a closed plane curve enclosing the origin $(0,0)$. I think the following equation holds:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{\textbf{r}(\theta)}{|\textbf{r}(\theta)|^2}=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Can anyone give a proof?

Comment: Why is the integral from 0 to 2$\pi$? That seems a bad condition, because I think you for this closed curve you can have $r(0)=r(k), k\neq 2\pi$?

Comment: Here, $\theta$ denotes the angle of the point $\textbf{r}$ in the plane w. r. t. the x-axis. For example, let $\textbf{r}(\theta)=(a \cos(\theta),a \sin(\theta))$, which is a circle.

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting question, will think about it.

Comment: I suppose that in the denominator $|r(\theta)|$ shouldn't be squared? Then it's provable.

Comment: Why do you think this equality holds? If $r(\theta)>0$ then how could this integral possibly be $0$? Unless you mean that $r$ is a vector and the integral equals $(0,0)?$ But then, again, why do you expect this equation to hold?

Comment: Yes, I mean $\textbf{r}$ is a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not true. This is a counterexample:
$$
\mathbf r(t)=\bigl(2+\sin(t+1)\bigr)\,(\cos t,\sin t).
$$
It is true, as commented by Macrophage, if the denominator is $|\mathbf r(t)|$.

Comment: Thanks for your example. You are correct. Someone wrote down this formula and said it can be shown by some physical arguments. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> In $\textbf r(\theta)$, $\theta$ denotes the angle of the point $\textbf r$ in the plane w. r. t. the [positive] x-axis.

Thus, $r(\theta)=(a(\theta)\cos\theta,a(\theta)\sin\theta)$ for some nonzero scalar function $a(\theta)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{\textbf{r}(\theta)}{|\textbf{r}(\theta)|^2}=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{(a(\theta)\cos\theta,a(\theta)\sin\theta)}{|a(\theta)|^2}=(\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{a(\theta)},\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\frac{\sin\theta}{a(\theta)})
\end{eqnarray}

(Intuitively, $\textbf r(\theta)$ describes closed curves that can be obtained by radially expanding or contracting a unit circle in the Cartesian plane)

Comment: Since $1/a(\theta)$ is a periodic function, it can be expended as a power series in terms of $\cos(n\theta)$ and $\sin(n\theta)$. Then, the proof follows by proving that the integration of every term is zero. Is it correct? A good idea.

Comment: @D.J.Z. I think the result is not true unless you replace square of the modulus with just the modulus of r....